# Android show status bar while start activity not smooth

Tags: android, statusbar

#### Case:

The status bar performs a jump while Main2Activity shows up.

---

- How can I avoid this?
- There should be some method to fix this?
- Does this matters with the app theme?

---

#### Devices:

Nexus 5, Android 6.0

#### Code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dealWithSystemUiAction();
            }
        });
    }


    private void dealWithSystemUiAction() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, Main2Activity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I think it is because you are using `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` so status bar appear on touch and then disappear after sometime.

Comment: @camelCaseCoder Yes, but it's necessary.  I need MainActivity to be a full screen activity with no status bar. But Main2Activity should be a activity with status bar shown. So any other solutions?